# What code does iPhone Compass use to display location coordinates even without an internet connection?

Tags: ios, gps, geolocation, compass-geolocation

I have made an app that will display the co-ordinates of the user location. It works fine with Wifi connectivity but fails to display anything despite waiting for 2-3 minutes, when there isn't internet connection. I was curious how Compass, iphone's inbuilt app could display the coordinates in a matter of seconds after calibration.

My following code, which is written in swift, finds the address based on the co-ordinates from GPS. I'm just confused why this code isn't able to display latitude and longitude in the absence of internet connectivity.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController2: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet var locality: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var postalCode: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var AdministrativeArea: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var country: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var latitude: UILabel?
    @IBOutlet var longitude: UILabel?

    var currentLocation = CLLocation()
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyThreeKilometers
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        currentLocation = locationManager.location
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)
    {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

            if (error != nil)
            {
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)

                return
            }

            if placemarks.count > 0
            {
                let pm = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            }
            else
            {
                println("Error with the data.")
            }
        })
    }

    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark)
    {
        /
        locality?.text = "\(placemark.locality)"
        postalCode?.text = "\(placemark.postalCode)"
        AdministrativeArea?.text = "\(placemark.administrativeArea)"
        country?.text = "\(placemark.country)"
        latitude?.text = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.latitude)"
        longitude?.text = "\(currentLocation.coordinate.longitude)"
    }
```